# jQuery validation plugin , add custom method

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to add a method that validate a field to see if it contains a number value.

so this is what i did, however it is not doing the check for me.
anyone has any idea?

thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $.validator.addMethod('positiveNumber',
            function(value) {
                return Number(value) > 0;
            }, 'Enter a positive number.');

    });
```

and

```
jQuery('form').validate();
jQuery('.validateFieldToCheck').rules('add', {
            positiveNumber:,
            messages: {
                required: 'Field must contain a number.'
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just realized that I have some syntax error, and that was cause some weird behavior of the jQuery validation. Problem solved now once I correct those mistakes.

thanks anyways.

Comment: jesus, what was the syntax error? what was the solution? 2000 views and you accepted your answer saying "well i figured it out, go ahead and figure it out yourselves too"

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you should try, instead of the second block of code you have, the following:

```
$('#your-form-id').validate({
            rules: {
                yourFormFieldIdToCheck: {
                    required: true,
                    positiveNumber:true  
                }
            },
            messages: {
                yourFormFieldIdToCheck: {
                    required: "This value is required",
                    positiveNumber:"Positive numbers only please"
                }
            }
});
```

to then verify if is valid as

```
if ($('#your-form-id').valid() == true) { // Proceed with whatever ...
```